# Classify all harmonic $f$ s.t. $f=gh$

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

More specifically, $f$ harmonic s.t.:

$f: (0,1)^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x,y)=g(x)h(y)$ and $g,h \in C^{2}((0,1))$

Bear in mind that I am at calc III level, having just started an introductionary course for PDEs. This is our very first exercise. I have several ideas/starting points but things complicate so quickly that I have trouble estimating which one is promising and how to marry them.

First I deduced the obvious requirement of

$\forall x,y \in (0,1): g''(x)h(y)=-g(x)h''(y)$

Secondly, by mean value property, $f$ is of the given form iff

$\forall B_{r}((x,y)) \subseteq (0,1)^{2}: f(x,y)=g(x)h(y)=\frac{1}{\pi r^{2}}\int_{B_{r}((x,y))}g(x)h(y)d\mathcal{L}^{2}$

Where to go from here? Do I need to make specific computations and/or coordinate transformations with that integral? One idea I had was that if $f$ satisfies the above it is harmonic iff

$\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}\int_{B_{r}((x,y))}g(x)h(y)d\mathcal{L}^{2}=-\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial y^{2}}\int_{B_{r}((x,y))}g(x)h(y)d\mathcal{L}^{2}$

If I can verify whether all conditions to exchange order of differentiation and integration are met (or restrict $f,g,h$ such that they are), I could proceed with

$\int_{B_{r}((x,y))}\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}g(x)h(y)d\mathcal{L}^{2}=-\int_{B_{r}((x,y))}\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial y^{2}}g(x)h(y)d\mathcal{L}^{2} \iff \int_{B_{r}((x,y))}g''(x)h(y)d\mathcal{L}^{2}=-\int_{B_{r}((x,y))}g(x)h''(y)d\mathcal{L}^{2}$

In retrospect, these steps look like circular reasoning, I basically just integrated both sides of the equation I deduced at the start over arbitrary Balls s.t. $B_{r}((x,y)) \subseteq (0,1)^{2}$.

At this point I am a bit lost. Product rule? Change of coordinates/Fubini? I even have trouble knowing when I am done, because I have no idea how much you can narrow down the class of functions $g,h$ satisfying this.

Comment: Your identity $g''(x)h(y) = -g(x)h''(y)$ can be rearranged slightly to $\frac{g''(x)}{g(x)} = -\frac{h''(y)}{h(y)}$. The LHS is a function of $x$, the RHS is a function of $y$..

Comment: Adding to what @CameronWilliams says: Make sure you understand that the LHS and RHS are equal to *one* constant $\lambda$. Then solve the resulting ODEs and check whether the solutions are harmonic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $y.$ Then your equation tells you that $h^{\prime\prime}(x) = c h(x),$ so on horizontal lines your function is a complex exponential in $x$ with coefficient depending on $y.$ The same is true on vertical lines, so the log of your function is **linear** in both $x$ and $y.$